# Change orientation of object with respect to x-y rectilinear plane

Tags: modeling, objects, transforms

If an object imported from an stl file is oriented along the the x-y coordinate plane how can I rotate it so that it is vertical?

Answer (score -1):

You can [rotate](https://www.blender.org/manual/editors/3dview/transform/rotate.html) it.

then  [apply rotation](https://www.blender.org/manual/editors/3dview/transform/transform_control/reset_object_transformations.html#apply-object-transformations).

here is a tutorial on the basics of [navigation](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xT2mtoDnSzM)

Comment: please help us to keep the quality of the site by making your answers more detailed. Instead of relying on links only, please make your answer stand on its own. Links change all the time (yes, even those to the blender manual), If those links change, then your post will make no sense. Please add more information: What is the procedure for rotating? How and why do you apply transformations?